# Setting up a one to many through relationship in sequelize

Tags: database, sequelize.js, relationship

I am new using Sequelize, I want to know if it's possible to set up a `one-to-many through` relationship.

A possible case of this relationship can be seen in the below case;

`A school has many students through a Class`

`A student belongs to a school through Class`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This way:

```
School.belongsToMany(Student, { through: 'school_student' });
Student.belongsTo(School, { through:  'school_student'});
```

Note that this implies the existence of a "school_student" table, which will be created automatically for you if you're using Model.sync(), but if not, you'll need to create it your self(preferably via migrations). If you create it, make sure it has schoolId and studentId columns.

Comment: Thanks @I.brod. In doing that, do I need to populate the `school_student` table when creating a new student or it would be auto populated?

Comment: once you do Student.create(), the returned object should have a method called addSchool

Comment: I have an issue setting up your answer; I get the below error:

`Executing (default): SELECT "id", "first_name", "class_id", "schoolId" FROM "Students" AS "Student" WHERE ("Student"."first_name" = 
'Doubofa' AND "Student"."last_name" = 'Philimon' AND "Student"."date_of_birth" = '2020-12-12');

SequelizeDatabaseError: column "schoolId" does not exist`

For some reason, sequelize is checking for `studentId` on the student's table, which doesn't exist.

However, it works perfectly for a `many-to-many through` relationship, where I did 

`Student.belongsToMany(...)`